# Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (= 3.2.0) in any repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm installing ruby on rails on my OS X 10.7 machine and trying to follow along with this book: [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails).

Anyway I have installed Ruby 1.9.3 and then ran `gem install rails` and it pulled down rails 3.1.3, now the book says when I run 'rails -v' I should get 3.2.0 or NEWER.

I checked out http://rubygems.org/gems/rails and it says the latest version is rails 3.2.0 RC2, how is it that the book specifies (in multiple places to it's not a typo) that it should be 3.2.0 or NEWER when 3.2.0 isn't even released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you want the latest unstable version, run this:

```
gem install rails --pre
```

It'll install the latest RC.

**EDIT**: as to why the included 3.2.0 when it is not out yet, I can't answer for them! Maybe you have a "beta" version of the book?

Comment: I know I can use `--pre` to install the pre-release version but i'm just wondering why the book is telling me I need 3.2.0 or newer (and they are saying it as if it is released)

Comment: then this is not a question for StackOverFlow but for PragProg guys or authors

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're specifying an explicit dependency on a future version of Rails, probably something like `gem 'rails', '3.2.0'`. If you indeed want to use this version, you'll have to settle for one of the release candidates for now:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.0.rc2'
```

Or borrow a time machine.